# Textmate: Find and add numeric values

Tags: textmate

I want to find and replace numerics in my html file as follows e.g.: href="#1" to href="#12". Basically I want to add 10 to the exiting value

```
 from
 <p><a href="#2">bla bla</a>
 <p><a href="#3">bla bla</a>
 to
 <p><a href="#chapter12">bla bla</a>
 <p><a href="#chapter13">bla bla</a>
```

how can I do this in textmate?

Comment: you may not be able to do this directly in textmate very easily. thought with a scripting language like Python or Ruby, you could fairly quickly feed the file in and perform the arithmetic find and replace - see: http://ask.metafilter.com/117098/Regex-Help-for-Adding-14-to-a-Series